# French version of “I know X like the back of my hand”?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

In English it's very common to use the expression “I know it like the back of my hand” to express that you know or understand something extremely well.

In French I found “connaitre par cœur”, “connaitre comme le fond de sa poche” and “connaitre sur le bout des doigts”. In which context is each of those appropriate?

Are there any other French expressions of similar popularity and meaning?

Comment: Les traductions les plus courantes : Je le connais comme le fond de ma poche ; je le connais par cœur

Comment: When I was kid, my mom funnily used "Je te connais comme si je t'avais fait" ie "I know you like if I had made you".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say *connaître sur le bout des doigts*, the others have slightly different meanings

- *connaître par cœur* is straightforward knowing by heart. See also *apprendre par cœur* → learn by rote
- *connaître comme le fond de sa poche* or just *comme sa poche* is generally use for place, e.g. one usually knows his hometown comme le fond de sa poche.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the French expression "*je connais X sur le bout des doigts*" is the closest to  “*I know X like the back of my hand*” in terms of meaning and image. For meaning only, I agree with cl-r's suggestions.